# Generic CSS Selector that checks whether the current element has specified attributes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Don't know if this is a duplicate or not but having a hard time finding the answer to this. I'm looking for a CSS selector that generically and *individually* targets the *current* element/tag (which is arbitrary) to see if it contains a specified set of attributes. Does anybody know how to express a selector like that?

An example of what I'm talking about would be, given two different tags (representing components) that contain the same attribute:

```
<div data-colorMode="light">...</div>
<nav data-colorMode="dark">...</nav>
```

I only want the generic selector to grab the individual component when running CSS related things at the local component level if that makes any sense. Hopefully I'm not speaking nonsense as I'm just an advanced beginner at CSS.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.myclass[data-colorMode=light] { background-color: lightblue; }
.myclass[data-colorMode=dark] { background-color: darkblue; }
```

Usage:

```
<div class="myclass" data-colorMode="light">Hello</div>
<nav class="myclass" data-colorMode="dark">World</nav>
```

Only elements which have the class "myclass" will be affected by the rule. I think this is what you described.